# Weird bug whilst making android app

Tags: java, android, integer, save, loading

So I'm trying to make my first ever Android app. It's just a simple tally counter for now but I've come across a weird bug.

You see, I've got a simple save and load function, an increment, decrement and reset button. and a TextView that displays the value all together (see below).

Now when I increment the value up to say 10 and close the app, it saves as it should and when I open the app again, it does come back as 10. However, when I then increment up to say 30 or 100, close and restart the value does not stick and comes out as either -1 or a value that is completely different.

What could be happening?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    int value;

    TextView textView_value;
    final String filename = "tallyCountPlus";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadValue(filename);

        textView_value = (TextView) findviewById(R.id.textView_value);
        textView_value.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }

    /** Called when the user presses the increment button */
    public void incValue(View view) {
        value++;
        textView_value.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }

    /** Called when the user presses the decrement button */
    public void decValue(View view) {
        if (value > 0) {
            value--;
        }
        textView_value.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }

    /** Called when the user presses the reset button */
    public void resetValue(View view) {
        value = 0;
        textView_value.setText(Integer.setString(value));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveValue(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadValue(filename);
        textView_value.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        saveValue(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void loadValue(String name) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(name);

            value = fis.read();

            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveValue(String name, int context) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(name, context);

            fos.write(value);

            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know what my problem could be?

Thanks.

Jamie.

EDIT:

So I think I've fixed the bug by doing:

```
private void loadValue(String filename) {
/* this is wrapped in a try-catch statement */
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(name);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    value = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());

    fis.close() /* Not sure if this is actually neccessary? */

    if (value == -1) {
        value = 0;
    }
}

private void saveValue(String name) {
/* This is also wrapped in a try-catch statement */
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String data = Integer.toString(value);
    fos.write(data.getBytes());

    fos.close();
}
```

And after putting in a couple of values, it seems to work fine. However, I'm unsure as to whether it is appending or deleting the previous value and replacing it... I'd rather the latter to prevent the save file from getting too big.

Comment: check the u have provided the external write permission

Comment: I don't need the external write permission as I'm using internal storage, not external.

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy()` is not dependable. Just stick with `onPause()`. Also, in general, for the methods that handle events when the activity is "going away", you should call the `super` method *after* your own code, to ensure your custom code can still execute.

Other things to check might be:

- Is the method that saves the output *replacing* the previous file, or just *appending* to it?
- Are you properly loading and saving each time?
- If the file is properly loaded, is the value making it into the `TextView`? You might need to construct an anonymous `Runnable` that ensures that the `TextView` is updated by the main (UI) thread.

Sprinkle log statements liberally throughout the code to keep track of what the tally is, what you get out of the file, etc.

When diagnosing file issues, it helps to test on an emulator, which gives you root access to the device storage.

Comment: I have Cyanogen 13 on my dev phone so having root access is not an issue. However, I cannot actually find where the file is saved to.

Comment: Try `/data/data/your.app.package.name/files/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify loadValue() method. You are assigning fis.read() to value which returns next byte or -1 if EOF reached.

```
private void loadValue(String name) {
    try {
        FileInputStream in = openFileInput(name);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        value = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That causes an exception in main which is a NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "[]"

and when I put a catch statement for said NFE, it just goes back to 0 every time I close and launch it.